# Prevent user from selecting choice on quiz more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a JS quiz. The problem is that when an user selects a choice, (s)he has a short time frame to change his answer. The user can also click the right answer as many times as (s)he wants and the quiz would count that as well. I have tried creating a transparent overlay but that would block some buttons. Is there a way to do this in jQuery / JS alone?

I know it has something to do with the "submit" conditional:

```
if (submt) {
  //alert("submit");
  submt = false;
  setTimeout(processQuestion,3000);
}
```

[Here's the complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/7Du6N/340open_in_new)

Comment: Why don't you simply make a `NEXT` button? In 3 seconds I cannot even read the full tip answer

Comment: I plan to remove the explanation. Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just this at the top of your click handler?

```
if (!submt) {
    return;
}
```

That way you just ignore clicks after the user has already made their selection.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Du6N/341/